# Running my discord bot shows "[RecursionError] maximum recursion depth exceeded "

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making A Discord Bot in Discord.py....I want to make it more functional...but Python is not allowing me to do it.

This time I have added a Translating Method in my discord bot...but while running it...it shows

```
[RecursionError]
maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I am running my Discord Bot file in repl.it...so that it runs forever.

Here is my code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import random
from langdetect import detect  #upm package(langdetect)
from translate import Translator
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents, pass_context=True)
TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN'


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Succesfully logged in as {0.user}".format(bot))


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    for channel in member.guild.channels:
        if str(channel.id) == '818849631907479555':
            await channel.send(f'Welcome!! {member.mention}')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    eng = detect(message)
    if eng != 'en':
        translator = Translator(to_lang="English")
        translation = translator.translate(message)
        me = translation.content.lower()

    hello_msgs = [
        'hello <@!820999504496820224>', 'hi <@!820999504496820224>',
        'heya <@!820999504496820224>', 'hoi <@!820999504496820224>'
    ]

    bad_words = ['ghost', 'abcd']

    if any(x in me for x in bad_words):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(
            f'''{message.author.mention} BAD HUMAN!! Don't use bad word''')

    elif any(y in me for y in hello_msgs):
        hello = ['Hello! ', 'Hi! ', 'Hoi! ', 'Heya! ']
        h_msg = random.choice(hello)
        pre_msg = message.author.mention
        se_msg = h_msg + pre_msg
        await message.channel.send(se_msg)
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command(name='kill')
async def on_kill(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Police: You are arrested!! Now chill in jail')
    user = ctx.author
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="JAIL")
    await user.add_roles(role)


@bot.command(name='ping')
async def on_ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'My ping is {bot.latency}!')


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I have tried every possible solution....but still, it does not work...
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "I have tried every possible solution" This is impossible, since otherwise you wouldn't be asking here - you would know that we couldn't possibly tell you something you hadn't already tried. It also comes across as an attempt to pre-empt people asking you what you tried. Note: we are not fooled. We still want to know *what, specifically, you tried*. You should pick one or more of the things you tried and show them.

Comment: At the very least, you should demonstrate the effort you made to *diagnose and understand* the problem. You showed an error message about recursion depth; did you *intend* for the code to be recursive? Do you *understand* why a recursive call is occuring? Did you *try to figure out* what the pattern of recursion is, for example by looking at the stack trace?

Comment: Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to figure out how to make a [minimum reproducible example](http://sscce.org).